# Jenkins + Docker Change workspace layout

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to setup a yocto build job on a jenkins server. I am running into an issue where I need a specific folder layout where the repository contents are cloned to.
The jenkins its self is running as a docker container with a connection to the "outside" docker socket to launch and start containers. Furthermore I need to cache the build directory (>20GB) in between runs, otherwise this will take ages in between runs.

I tried the following Jenkinsfile to see the layout jenkins uses:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'XXXXXX/yocto:latest'
            args '-v $HOME/yocto:/home/yocto'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
                sh 'echo "$(pwd)"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This yields me the following output:

```
+ls
<contents of the repository>
+pwd
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXXXX-yocto_master
```

How ever in order for my bootstrap script to work (which I can not change easily because loads of other people are relying on it) I would need the following folder layout:

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXXXXX-yocto_master
└── new_reposiotry_name
    └── <repository contents>
```

How can I instruct the Jenkins pipeline to not clone the contents of the repository into the workspace but rather put it into a folder? I know this can be done by moving files around but I would try to avoid it if there is some other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples way probaly is to use the option checkoutToSubdirectory('myRepoDir')

```
pipeline {
    options{
        checkoutToSubdirectory('myRepoDir')
    }
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'XXXXXX/yocto:latest'
            args '-v $HOME/yocto:/home/yocto'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
                sh 'echo "$(pwd)"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can have it as a pipeline step and use the `skipDefaultCheckout()` option to ignore default git checkout.

```
pipeline {
    options{
        skipDefaultCheckout()
    }
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'XXXXXX/yocto:latest'
            args '-v $HOME/yocto:/home/yocto'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout SCM'){
            steps{
                 dir('myRepoDir'){
                     git branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'your-credential', url: 'your-repo'
                 }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
                sh 'echo "$(pwd)"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for poiting me in the right direction, now that I knew what to search for (options) I found this option `checkoutToSubdirectory('foobar')` resulting in exactly the setup I need

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, will add that on the answer.